# When click on <li> I when display none div and display table one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on a li on my navbar, I want display a div and display none others div.
I use jquery.

Example: If I click on Entreprise, I want show the block where id is "entreprise" and hide the others div

jquery:

```js
 $(function() 
 {
 
 if(document.getElementById("entreprise").click()){
  document.getElementById("entreprise").css("display","table");
  document.getElementById("service").css("display","none");
  document.getElementById("information").css("display","none");
 }

 if(document.getElementById("service").click()){
  document.getElementById("entreprise").css("display","none");
  document.getElementById("service").css("display","table");
  document.getElementById("information").css("display","none");
 }
 
 if(document.getElementById("information").click()){
  document.getElementById("entreprise").css("display","none");
  document.getElementById("service").css("display","none");
  document.getElementById("information").css("display","table");
 }
 
});
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 5%">
  <div class="row">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation"  id="entreprise"><a href="#">Entreprise</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"  id="service"><a href="#">Service</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" id="information"><a href="#">Information</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="deconnexion.php">Deconnexion</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="entreprise" style="display:none">
   <p> hi</p>
  </div>  
  <div class="row" id="service" style="display:none">
   <p> hi 2 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="information" style="display:none">
   <p> hi 3</p>
  </div>
 </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have same id's for button and div.

Actually, you can't have same id's at all. That's why they are id's, unique identifiers.

You could do something like this:

```
 $('#entrepriseButton').on('click',function(){
    $('#entreprise').show();
    $('#service').hide();
    $('#information').hide();
 });
```

But of course change button id to `#entrepriseButton`

Full example here https://jsfiddle.net/5k9jdo80/

**Update**

Even better solution would be to leave id's for buttons, remove them from hidden div's and add custom attribute (`show-hide` in my case) to hidden div's and then just use jQuery like this:

```
 $('li').on('click',function(){
    $(".hidden[show-hide="+$(this).attr('id')+"]").show();
    $(".hidden[show-hide!="+$(this).attr('id')+"]").hide();
 });
```

Full example https://jsfiddle.net/5k9jdo80/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not correct jQuery code, also I noted that you are using the "id" property in the HTML code 2 times the same, the ID property should be an unique identifier and should only exist one time. So it should work like this:

```
$(function() 
 {

    $('.nav li a').on('click', function(e) {
        var _target = $(this).attr('href'); //it will get something like #enterprise
        var $target_div = $(_target); //transform it into a selector

        if ( _target.indexOf('#') > -1 ) { //if the link has # it means it has a div#wharever target to show, so cancel the link opening effect
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if ( $target_div.length ) { //check if it exists
            $target_div.css({'display': 'table'}); //apply display: table style, or just use $target.show(); to apply display: block

            $target_div.siblings().hide(); //hide it siblings (if #enterpise is the target, #service and #information will get hidden)
        }
    });

});
```

And the HTML code should look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#enterprise">Entreprise</a></li> <!-- use the id of the target in the href property -->
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#information">Information</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="deconnexion.php">Deconnexion</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tabs"> <!-- insert the targets inside a div, otherwise the .nav container with class ".row" will be a sibling -->

    <div class="row" id="enterprise" style="display:none">
        <p> hi</p>
    </div>      
    <div class="row" id="service" style="display:none">
        <p> hi 2 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="information" style="display:none">
        <p> hi 3</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

You can see a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jadielh/cwyub0xo/