# Load div into target when image Nav is clicked and display none; remove div when not in use

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Load div into target from onclick using image nav. Then I want to hide divs that are not active. The 1st div should initially load when page loads. I have searched but can't find a solution.

```js
// JavaScript Document
const mus = document.querySelector("#mus"),
  albNav = mus.querySelector(".albnav img"),
  /*hideAlbNav = mus.querySelector(""),*/
  tunes = mus.querySelector("#tunes"),
  gen0Nav = mus.querySelector("img #gen0"),
  gen1Nav = mus.querySelector("img #gen1"),
  gen0Tunes = mus.querySelector("#tunes .gen0"),
  gen1Tunes = mus.querySelector("#tunes .gen1");


/*$(document).on('click', '.menu', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
});*/

tunes.style.display = 'none';

$("albNav").on('click', function() {
  $(this).attr('.menu');
  $('tunes').hide();
  $('tunes').show();
});
```

```html
<div id="mus">
  <div class="albnav">
    <img id="gen0" class="menu" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="xxx" />
    <img id="gen1" class="menu" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="xxx" />
    <img id="gen2" class="menu" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="xxx" />
    <img id="gen3" class="menu" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="xxx" />
    <img id="gen4" class="menu" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="xxx" />
    <img id="gen5" class="menu" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="xxx" />
  </div>
  
  <div id="tunes">
    <div class="gen0">Gen 0</div>
    <div class="gen1">Gen 1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="js/stQ-plrnav-12-14-22.js"></script>    -->
```

Answer (score 0):

isherwood DID NOT find the solution. The author mim did. isherwood Please stop editing my post just to save face. The original answer by the author mim is as follows:
No thanks to isherwood, who has deleted his comments..haha, I found the answer from Jakob @ [When click on <li> I when display none div and display table one div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529459/when-click-on-li-i-when-display-none-div-and-display-table-one-div). Here is the solution:

```
 $('.menu').on('click',function(){
    $(".hidden[show-hide="+$(this).attr('id')+"]").show();
    $(".hidden[show-hide!="+$(this).attr('id')+"]").hide();
 });
```

```
.albnav {
   position: relative;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
   gap: 4px;
   width: 80%;
   /*height: auto;*/
       border-style:dashed;
   border-color: #F431F0;
}
.menu {
   position: relative;
   width: 14.75%;
   object-fit: cover;
   max-width: 85px;
   height: auto;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding: 5px 0 5px 2px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.active, .albnav img:hover {
   /*background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);*/
   opacity: 0.8;
}
#tunes {
   /*margin-top;: 100px;*/
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px;
      border-style:dashed;
   border-color: #EB1215;
}
.hidden:first-of-type {display:block}
.hidden {display:none}
```

```
      <div class="albnav">
         <img id="gen0" class="menu" src="genpx.png"/>
         <img id="gen1" class="menu" src="genpx1.png"/>
         <img id="gen2" class="menu" src="genpx2.png"/>
         <img id="gen3" class="menu" src="genpx3.png"/>
         <img id="gen4" class="menu" src="genpx.png"/>      
      </div>
      
      <div id="tunes">
         <div id="tun0" class="hidden" show-hide="gen0">Gen 0</div>
         <div id="tun1" class="hidden" show-hide="gen1">Gen 1</div>
         <div id="tun2" class="hidden" show-hide="gen2">Gen 2</div>
         <div id="tun3" class="hidden" show-hide="gen3">Gen 3</div>
         <div id="tun4" class="hidden" show-hide="gen4">Gen 4</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: For better vice quality: Use date attributes instead. And get the items index or use something else instead of relying on numbered IDs

Comment: thx cloned. I only used the numbered IDs for example. My own code has unique names. I will reframe from using numbers here moving forward. I don't understand what you mean by vice quality; which data attributes are you referring?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, it should mean code quality :) instead of `show-hide` attribute I would use `data-show-hide` . even tough it seems that data-attributes are less and less popular because people just use whatever attribute they want on an element

Comment: @cloned, I have taken note. Thx